# Is there a chance of uniqid('foo') having the same value as uniqid('foo2') in PHP?

Tags: php

Since `uniqid()` provides a random string based on the value given, is it even possible, and if so, what are the chances of `uniqid('foo')` equalling `uniqid('foo2')`?

Comment: There's a very useful comment on that:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#95001

Comment: See also [this question over on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/76229/19717), which is about `rand()`.  It happens that `uniqid()` uses the same entropy mechanism and plays a role in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniqid()` does not provide a random value based on the string.

Per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

`foo` and `foo2` will only be used to prefix the value. For example, this code:

```
echo uniqid('foo') . "\n";
echo uniqid('foo2');
```

would output:

```
foo510aac3bedcdb
foo2510aac3bedd03
```

As long as the prefix is different, the values won't collide. However with the same prefix, a collision would be possible if the 2 requests are made at the same microsecond. If you are worried about collision, set the second parameter to `true` to add more entropy to your value.